# wamp server slowed down

Tags: wamp, wampserver

My WAMP server was running really quickly without any problems.
When I restarted my computer and the server, it now takes a while longer to load any localhost pages.  Have tried restarting again (both the server and computer).

Any suggestions on what could have caused this and solutions?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/software tech support.

Comment: @MarcB Questions about general computing hardware and software are on-topic for Stack Overflow if they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. I think a WAMP setup on a PC qualifies as such.

Comment: You can ask this kind of questions on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @GolezTrol: at some point you have to draw the line, and I'm drawing this behing the "this is server configuration, not programming" line.

Comment: I think WAMP server on a PC is (part of) a development environment, but let's agree to disagree.

Answer (score 3):

Few things you should follow:

**TCP/IP**

Reset Winsock and TCP/IP back to their original state. Then reboot.

Run from an admin level command-line; right-click cmd.exe, select ‘Run as Administrator’.

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset C:\resetlog.txt
```

Other software can attach filters to Winsock, and change the TCP/IP parameters, which causes Apache to stop responding to requests (with the problem manifesting as a slow page load, half page load, etc).

**DNS**

Make sure your system is not using old, invalid, non-working, and slow DNS Servers.

Run `ipconfig /all`

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
                                       209.244.0.3
```

The above should list the DNS Servers assigned to you by your ISP (via DHCP), or display a list of public DNS Servers that are set via your Router or OS settings.

Flush Windows DNS Cache: `ipconfig /flushdns`

**YOUR BROWSER**

Slow response times for Chrome, Firefox, and IE can be indicative of –

1. Bad Proxy settings that are timing out:

   Bypass proxy server for local addresses by creating Exceptions for your domain-names, and IP address 127.0.0.1.
2. Different plugins, and also phishing and malware protection settings:

   Check your Browser’s active plugins, try disabling them. Check protection settings, exclude your domain-names.
3. Stale cache results:

   Clear your Browser’s Cache. Also run Windows Disk Cleanup.
4. Clear Your WAMP Log Files

   Apache maintains website access and error logs that can grow in size very quickly. PHP also has similar logs (if enabled via configuration).

   ```
   C:\WampDeveloper\Logs
   C:\WampDeveloper\Temp
   ```

   Once Apache log files grow in size to above several 100 MB, performance issues can arise. Also the Temp folder holds lots of session and temporary data files that don’t get properly cleaned up, which causes it’s own issues.

You can clear out the Log and Temp files like this:

- Make sure Apache and MySQL are not running.
- Open the command-line (run: `cmd.exe`).
- Delete all the websites log files:

  ```
  del /S C:\WampDeveloper\Logs\*log.txt
  ```
- Delete all the temporary files –

  ```
  del /S C:\WampDeveloper\Temp\*
  ```

Since this is a pure wildcard file-name delete (*), it will ask you if you want to delete all the files each time it finds a new sub-directory… As it prompts you, press the ‘y’ or ‘Y’ key, then press the ‘Enter’ key; or add in the /Q switch (`del /S /Q …`) to tell it not to prompt you at all.

The above will delete all the log files and all the temp files, within all the sub-directories. Make sure you do this carefully (that you are using the right paths)!

If you do this manually, make sure to never delete the directories and sub-directories, just the files in them.

For more information follow the reference link,  It's little lengthier but worth reading.

https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow